# How can I display SVG code as image in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg

I have an API that is returning, among other things, an SVG image as ASCII text code. So I have that in a value. I am trying to display it as part of my page. It's just giving me a blank image.

This is the JSFiddle of my attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/c0p4ku78/

The essences of the code is effectively this:

```
<template>
<div id="app">
  <svg>{{circle}}</svg>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "ImageShower",
  data: () {
    return {
      circle: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?> ... `
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

In the real code, circle comes from a web service and is not hard coded into the view component. But it looks more or less as is abbreviated here.

How can I display this SVG as an image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could render it using `v-html` directive :

```
<template>
<div id="app">
  <div v-html="circle"></div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "ImageShower",
  data: () {
    return {
      circle: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?> ... `
    }
  },
}
</script>
```